# how can i inject a bunch of images without moving the items below

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have  the following code:

```
  <br/> <div id='people'></div> <br/>
  a bunch of text . .
```

So the people div is empty to start and then i have javascript (on the backend of a ajax callback populating that div with something like this:

```
    $("#people").html(data.results)
```

where data.results is a bunch of image html (", etc . .)

The issue is that when the images show up, this pushes down the "bunch of text" section and it looks a little jumpy.  I want it where the space is layed out in advance so when the .html() method is called, it simply populates the DOM with this image html but doesn't move or shift anything else on the page.

Comment: CSS: `#people {height:100px;overflow:auto;}`. Problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know how much space big the resulting images will need, you would give this div an initial height via the css `min-height`:

```
<br/> <div id='people' style='min-height: 250px;'></div> <br/>
```

Other than that, not really.  As you add content to your div, it will enlarge and push other things out of the way.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you could achieve this. The first would be to declare a rule in CSS that would set the height (or min-height) of the #people div if you know the height of the content coming in.

```
#people {
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Another option would be to allow the #people div content to scroll if it overflows the content area. This may or may not achieve the desired affect. (CSS)

```
#people {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```